# Redactor encode option like TinyMCE

Tags: .net, encoding, redactor

Was playing around with redactor and looking to replace a TinyMCE implementation.

The backend is ASP.NET and was trying really hard to not turn off RequestValidation of the page; as the current implementation uses the TinyMCE encoding="xml".

Redactor does not do this out of the box and could not find anything suitable online. So in the end created a really simple redactor plugin as follows.

```
if (typeof RedactorPlugins === 'undefined') var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.encode = {

init: function () {
    //add some submit handling to encode the html values
    var f = this.$source.closest('form');
    if (f)
        f.bind('submit', { el_id: this.$element.attr('id') }, this.encodeOnSubmit);

    },
encodeOnSubmit: function (e) {
    //grab the html off the element values and encode it
    var source = $('#' + e.data.el_id),
        h,
        e;
    if (!source)
        return;
    h = source.val();
     //encode the source value
    e = $('<div/>').text(h).html();
    //set the source to the encoded value
    source.val(e);
    }
}
```

This appears to work well (other than stripping of white space with the simple encoding implementation).

Was wondering if anyone else had a better way or some thoughts? Otherwise this maybe useful to others!